# HadoopRDD error while trying to count lines in a file hosted on local HDFS using spark shell

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I am new to Apache Spark, Scala and Hadoop tools.

I have setup a new local single node Hadoop cluster as mentioned [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Standalone_Operation) and have also setup spark providing a reference to this Hadoop environment as mentioned [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html).

I am able to verify that spark-shell, spark UI is up and running. Also, I am able to view the HDFS using [localhost](http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview).

To go a step further, I uploaded a sample file to HDFS and verified it is available using Hadoop localhost.

Now, I try to count the lines in the file using Java and spark-shell (Scala), but both the invocations are failing with this stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "dag-scheduler-event-loop" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputSplitWithLocationInfo
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPreferredLocations(HadoopRDD.scala:329)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:274)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:274)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:273)
... removed ...

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputSplitWithLocationInfo
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 32 more
```

Java Code (I am using spark-submit to specify the jar containing this code)

```
public static void main(final String... args) {
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("hello spark");

JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

JavaRDD<String> textload = ctx.textFile("README.md" );

System.out.println(textload.count());
}
```

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapred</artifactId>
    <version>0.22.0</version>
</dependency>


</dependencies>
```

Scala code on command line through spark-shell

```
sc.textFile("README.md").count
```

Version Details
Hadoop 2.4.0
Scala 2.11.8
Java 1.8
Apache Spark 2.2.1

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to Apache Spark, Scala and Hadoop

Then you should be using the latest, stable versions of each. For starters, download the latest Spark that includes Hadoop.

`hadoop-mapred` is a deprecated package  and you should not be using two different versions of Hadoop libraries. That explains why you would be getting ClassNotFoundException

If you downloaded Spark from the second link, it includes a version of Hadoop greater than 2.4, and those libraries are included on the Spark classpath, so you should not add them into your POM anyway. Find the [Java quickstart POM](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html)

I'll also point out that you should actually get HDFS working before you try to run Spark against it (assuming you need to use Hadoop instead of standalone Spark).

But you do not need Hadoop at all to run `spark.textFile("README.md" ).count` from Spark shell

Comment: These are the stable and infra supported versions at my place, not something that I control. I don't think I'm using two separate versions of Hadoop, I downloaded Spark without Hadoop and provided the 2.4.0 version of Hadoop. Yes, my HDFS and Hadoop cluster are running fine in isolation, I can get the localhost and can also see the uploaded file. In the real world, I want to access a HDFS file and do some transformations using Spark. Hence, I am trying to use spark-shell / Java to mimic the same using a sample file on HDFS. Hope this makes sense! How can I proceed?

Comment: Also, the only reason I added hadoop and map-red to my pom dependencies, is to see if it solves the issue, but, unfortunately it did not. Given this, how can I still utilize `hadoop-mapred` ? Let me know, if you need any other details.

Comment: I've never ran Spark with Hadoop less than 2.6, but you **are** using two different versions. You cannot use 0.22 libraries with 2.4.0... Wherever you pulled those versions from, they must be the same. You should only need Hadoop client, which includes mapreduce and hdfs dependencies http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.4.0   Besides that, you're not even using HDFS prefix in the filepath, so you're only reading a file from the directory where Spark is running

Comment: And like I said, Spark Core 2.2.1 already includes Hadoop 2.6.5 according to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.2.1  so, it's not really a good idea to downgrade that